# Installing Tensorflow (cpu) on Jenkins agent

Tags: python, jenkins, tensorflow

To run our tests on Jenkins, we need to install tensorflow in the virtual environment inside the Jenkins agent. I am getting the following error.

```
import tensorflow as tf
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import *
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in <module>
  raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
  from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in <module>
  _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
File "/prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
  _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: /prod/msp/build/slave1/workspace/Jobs_uiuc_simplesilo_master-7ENH27JSQENY42PFYNEOG3SJGXLTHWJC5Z6KNZUHEDUIGUWU5ZHQ/venv2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/_pywrap_tensorflow_internal.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

From the last line of error `PyUnicodeUCS4_FromString` I think this might be because of the wrong UCS type in python. However, I do not have sudo control over the Jenkins agents to install another python version. Any suggestions?

TF version : 1.6.0

Python verson: 2.7.3

Comment: Would Docker be an option?

Comment: actually I am trying docker right now :-)

Comment: I tried Docker myself and it worked.

Answer (score -1):

I tried running tensorflow inside a Docker image on Jenkins and it worked.